# display hidden content once facebook like button clicked

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

On external website (not fb page) would like to put like button where once visitor click like button , it shows certain content.

Here is the code i might thinking it works if i'm not wrong but needs more help !

```html
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<fb:like send="false" layout="button_count" width="100" show_faces="false"></fb:like>
<div id="hidden_content" style="display:none;">Thank You Dear</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
   FB.init({
   appId      : '185373538XXXXXX', // App ID
   status     : true, // check login status
   cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
   xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
   });

// Additional initialization code here
   FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function() {
   $('#hidden_content').show();
    });
   };

// Load the SDK Asynchronously
(function(d){
   var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
   js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
   js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
   d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
   }(document));
</script>
```

So any idea !
~Thanks a lot

Comment: So you think it might work but need more help? huh?!?

Comment: @Alexander Nenkov Well,just been thinking if it might be working or not but if you see it won't so it would be very helpful and thankful if you give me thoughts,ideas or reference to refer it in order to apply that idea ! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my idea (since you're looking for ideas and references).

edge.create will only fire when a user likes the link.  You will need to account for what happens when a user comes to your page that previously liked it.  I would suggest looking for a way to determine if the like has showed up.

Here's some documentation to read thru:
This might get you the graph id of your web page's url via the [object_url table](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/object_url/)
`SELECT url, id, type, site FROM object_url WHERE url = "http://developers.facebook.com/"`

Then see if you can track it down in either a [stream posting](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream/) or in a [like](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/like/)